# Vim helper to replace content in variable selection with register 0

Tags: vim

Is it possible to write a function or simply bind an accessible mapping to do what:

`ci"<C-r>0` but make the inside value symbol such as `"` variable?

Use case would be:

- I yank whatever I'd like through `v` (not `V` or `<C-v>`)
- I move to wherever I'd like to place this and say press `<leader>r"` to do the above
- If I pressed `<leader>r(` it would instead replace inside brackets
- To my knowledge this should not alter the register 0 and I would be able to just `.` any other replacements following the same pattern

Is the above possible?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because, as the vim tag states: For non-programming questions please use https://vi.stackexchange.com/ instead. Please delete this

Comment: Well... I can't delete this because there is an answer present.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to create a mapping with a dynamic left-hand side, but you can get close with `:help getcharstr()`:

```
nnoremap <expr> <key> 'ci' .. getcharstr() .. '<C-r>0<Esc>'
```

where the full command to be executed is constructed on the fly with user input.

You would use it like this:

```
<key>(
```

See `:help :map-<expr>`.